# What does Spring Data Elastic do if Elastic is down?

Tags: spring, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to know how Spring Data Elastic reacts if the Elastic database stops working. Does it store the data in cache or somewhere else? If not, is the data saved when the database was not working lost?

I can't find an answer to my question in the Spring documentation...

Can someone help me?

Comment: It will crash. Unless you programmed something to do something else it will just fail. Spring Data is just a thin wrapper around elastic making somethings easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls to Elasticsearch will throw an error coming from the underlying libraries. Spring Data Elasticsearch does not manage the data in any way, so it is in the application's responsibility to handle such exceptions.